# Determine limits for marginal pdf after Jacobian transformation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I am having problems with determining the integration limits for a pdf using the Jacobian.

Let  $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1].$

Let $Z = X -Y.\;$ 
I need to determine the pdf of $Z.$

Since the Jacobian need a square matrix, I added a second variable $U = Y.$

Then $|J| = 1.$

The combined pdf of $(Z,U)$ is $1.4\;$ (Right?).

To determining, the pdf of $Z,$ I need to integrate on $du.$ How do I determine the limits for $u?$

Comment: If $U=Y$ then of course the limits of $U$ must be the limits of $Y$?

Comment: I tried but the answer is diferent

Comment: Please post your effort, so that I can identify your mistakes. If you can take a photo of your work in a notebook, or type it in MathJax, it would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment.** Sometimes plotting a few well-chosen points can help to
establish the region of integration.

Below I mindlessly chose several thousand
$(X,Y)$-pairs at random and plotted them. The plot at left below suggests
the support of your bivariate distribution $(Z,U).$ Thinking more carefully,
can you say what four $(x,y)$-pairs get transformed to the corners of the parallelogram?

The histogram
suggests the distribution of $Z$ after you have 'integrated out' $U$. (Do you see that you need to have two integrals--one for $z < 0$ and one for $z > 0?)$

I hope this helps you with exact computation of the distribution of $Z.$
Can you see why the smallest and largest values of $Z$ would be $-1$ and $+1,$ respectively? Can you argue on intuitive grounds that $Z$ would have a mode at $0?$

[image]